# Differenitating between click and touch in list view

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented swipe behavior in my list view. So, basically, you can drag a item and item's alpha value would change accordingly (thanks to code by Roman Nurik [Roman Nurik](http://gist.github.com/romannurik/2980593) & [Tim Roes](http://github.com/timroes/SwipeToDismissUndoList)). The application is doing fine. Basically, on a generic list item, touch is treated as click, so for list without dragging facility, do not find difference between the two. But in my case, since I detect the co-ordinate at onTouch() to judge whether the user is scrolling left to right or right to left. My list does makes a difference between touch and click. So, I want to know do I dispatch a click event manually on list item so that even if user has not clicked and has dragged the item on touch, i still get to call OnListItemClick().

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time, no reply given.
Anyway, I thought to share my own findings on this question.
I found that there is no way of dispataching an event manually as far as I know. But I found that I could handle my problem in another way. Here is how I handled it.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

if(v.isPressed()
//
}
```

`isPressed()` would return when view is in pressed state. When it returns true, you can proceed further.

Hope it helps someone else.